# How do I start a tone and let it run indefinitely till i stop it explicitly?

Tags: c#, .net, audio, keydown, piano

I am trying to write a Piano application for my kid. What I am doing is using KeyDown and KeyUp Events inside a WinForm. The idea is to start emiting a frequency through the speaker in KeyDown event and then stop it in Keyup event. Just like in a piano :)

However, this is my first dabling in anything with Audio or Video. So, Is there a way to do it? Iz there a better way to do what I am suggesting. Note that I don't have access to midi or wav files or anything similar. Hence I can't start using samples that allow me to do this. Also note that I plan to go for more than just Piano frequencies.

Again, this is just for a kid to have fun (who is just 15 months old :))
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you don't want to use samples it will be much more complicated to make sounds other than the sine wave, as you'll have to make a synthesizer of some sort.

Comment: Try looking at these articles. 1. [Fundamentals of Sound: How to make music out of nothing at all](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/CPIAudio.aspx) 2. [Sound Generator – How to create alien sounds using mathematic formulas](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/SoundGenerator.aspx) 3. [Audio -Real low level sound generation in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3743591/479512)

Comment: @annonymously, Its not that I don't want to use midi or anything similar, just that I don't have access to existing files and don't have knowledge of how to create it. I really mean it when I say I am a beginner at this. :)

Answer (score 0):

Even the most basic onboard soundcard nowadays supports MIDI (I would really think). Check out this [C# MIDI Toolkit](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/MIDIToolkit.aspx).