# Simple 'sound player' control in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, audio, controls, media-player

I'd like to embed a simple WAV player into my Winforms program. It could look like this (derived from Media Player Classic):

[image]

I'd like the following 'features':

1. Controlling the slider of the sound/music shouldn't hog the other GUI's input (perhaps a background worker would help here)
2. The input will be WAVE for my requirements
3. There should be play/stop/pause buttons
4. The sound should play from a byte[] array in RAM (i.e. the WAV), and preferably not from a file
5. Granularity of slider should be fine (i.e. not like Youtube's coarse 'to-nearest-10-seconds' style)
6. Lightweight size (preferably already included in .NET if possible)
7. Low latency playing/stopping of sound (i.e. not waiting half a second after pressing the button)

After a little research, I found [this low-level sound generation question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743591/real-low-level-sound-generation-in-c) and also something called [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/). However, the former doesn't easily supply 'stop' functionality and has no slider code supplied. And the latter is a bit overkill (includes display of the WAV and many other features).

There's also the [Windows Media Player](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564585%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) control, but that's also a bit overkill (includes video etc.), and you apparently need to make sure that the required Windows Media Player version is installed on the user's computer, so compatibility may be an issue.

Anything, simple fast and effective here?

Comment: I won't post an answer since there may very likely be something that fits your needs exactly, but I can really recommend NAudio - it is a great library with lots of examples provided. You can easily grab just the parts you need from their examples.

Comment: Everything you ask for is provided by WMP, including the UI.  That it also supports video is irrelevant, just don't use it.  Compatibility is not an issue, works from XP to 8.

Comment: Thanks both - maybe I should investigate those options further.